# How to develop Tomcat applications with SpringSource Tool Suit?

Tags: java, tomcat, maven, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I want objects of my Tomcat web application to be controlled by Maven's pom and Spring's IoC, including session scoped beans. My application consists of several objects which are accessed from jsp files.

What is the best way to design such an application with suit tools? Should I use Spring MVC Project template though I don't want to implement MVC tiers? Or there is another template somewhere on the Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do using STS is like this. Go to

```
File --> New --> Project --> Maven Project--> Create a simple project (skip archtype)  --> Enter the Artifact details.
```

For Example: Group Id: `com.examples`
             Artifact Id: `MyProject`

Click on Finish.

Now Right Click the project in Project Explorer and the Select `Spring Tools--> Add Spring Project Nature.`

I usually use simple project because I like using the same `pom.xml` across projects and add/remove dependencies when needed.

Sample pom.xml to get going with Spring

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
     <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: But how to add "Tomcat Nature" so that I can debug an application on Tomcat with `WEB-INF` etc?

Comment: If you would like to do profiling on tomcat and if you use the provided VFabric tc Server. Just Double click the tc Server and there is a small tab called Insight. Check the Enable gathering of metrics box. After that restart your SpringToolSuite and deploy an application and point to http://localhost:8080/insight in your browser which will take you to the Insight Dashboard where you can look at various statistics collected by tomcat and others

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it has helped you in resolving the question in some way.

Comment: sorry I don't understand the answer yet. You told how to use Maven+Spring, but I don't understand, how to add Tomcat to this list; I have created HelloWordSerlvet class and it does not compile, because it has no HttpServlet class definition, which is normally located in <Tomcat>/lib directory. Also I don't see DispatcherServlet configuration to read context XML.